# При редиректе pm2 логов в файл на USB влешку иногда информация исчезает при отсоединении USB носителя

Tags: linux, pm2

У меня на USB есть SSH скрипт, который перенаправляет pm2 логи на это USB и сохраняет в файл. 
`pm2 logs > /media/usb1/temp.txt &`
Я вижу, что логи сохранились, но при отсоединении USB иногда они пропадают.
А иногда все ок.

Как решить проблему?
Спасибо.

Comment: флешку извлекаете корректно?

Comment: Это Linux серве. И там нет особых вариантов как извлечь.

Comment: @user249094, подразумевается отмонтировать ФС или, хотя бы, сделать `sync`...

Comment: У меня нет доступа к командной строке. В скрипте sync делаю. Флешка должна собирать на себя логи до момента извлечения. Может быть извлечина в любой момент.

Comment: Заметил сейчас, что когда смотрю содержимое флешки на пк, то сперва вижу в превью файла, что там что-то есть. Но потом все исчезает и файл пустой.

Comment: может есть способ разбить логи на более мелкие файлы?

Comment: Вроде работает копирование файла. Т.е. делаю редирект в файл А и периодически копирую его в файл B